# Querying an embedded document with javascript

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I have documents in mongodb that i'm accessing with mongoid that looks like this:

```
{
  "first_name": "Clarke",
  "last_name": "Kent",
  "vault_info": {
    "container": "names",
    "created_at": "2013-12-09T23:18:07.963Z",
    "updated_at": "2013-12-09T23:18:07.963Z",
    "vault_id": "4dc08baa97"
  }
}
```

I want to be able to query for it using the for_js method like this:

```
Model.for_js('this.vault_info.vault_id=="5088de6f12"')
```

If there is a single document in the database this works. If there is more than one it gives this error:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'vault_id' of undefined near '==\"5088de6f12\"' "
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Robert

Comment: Why are you using Javascript to perform that query?

Comment: I want my users to access their data through JavaScript.

Comment: It's extremely inefficient, and not how MongoDB performs at its best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the new documents you're adding don't have a `vault_info` property on them.  That means that `this.vault_info` evaluates to `undefined`, and you can't access any property (including `vault_id`) of `undefined`.

If you don't have to use the `for_js` method, just use the `where` method like this:

```
Model.where('vault_info.vault_id' => '5088de6f12')
```

Mongo intelligently filters out all documents that lack the vault_info property, so you don't get any errors about accessing properties of `undefined`.  JavaScript doesn't help you out like that, so if you do absolutely have to use the `for_js` method, you'll have to check each step of the way.  That'd look something like:

```
Model.for_js('this.vault_info && this.vault_info.vault_id=="5088de6f12"')
```

I'd encourage you to use the `where` method, though.  The less JavaScript you send to MongoDB the better.